# Is there a way to skip vignette build programatically?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I maintain an R package.  I have one vignette that builds on all other platforms but for some reason fails on CRAN's windows test server.  I'm at the point where I want to skip the vignette content entirely on windows in favor of a link to the website.

Is that flow control possible with R markdown?  Could I do something like this (in the same vein as `testthat::skip_on_os`):

```
if (os == "windows"){skip()}
# in which case all markdown below this line would not build
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. What is the error you get for the vignette build with windows. I would first try to just fix the problem itself.

Comment: I guess you know https://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx and https://builder.r-hub.io/ (in case you have no windows machine to run your tests)

Comment: Another hint that just came to my mind: You can also include static pdf's as vignette using  R.rsp as VignetteBuilder (might be an option if you do not change the vignette too often anyway).